# How can my code run perfectly, when i have a no-member error in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping, scapy

I've been playing around with the Scapy python library. My goal is to see which hosts are up on my local network, using the built-in arping() function in Scapy. The part that i do not understand is: while VSCode is giving me this error message: "Module 'scapy.all' has no 'arping' member"
the code still runs just fine, and i get the expected result in my terminal without any problems.

I want to understand what's the reason behind this error message, and if python is saying it cannot find arping how is it possible that the program still runs?

My exact code that I'm running:

```
import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)

scan('192.168.0.0/24')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior shows that the python environment used by the IntelliSense engine is different than the python environment in which you are running the code itself.

Try [changing your VS Code python interpreter/environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_environments) to match the python environment where you will be executing the code (see [the environment docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more details)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I found it a false positive, let me explain

first, you are importing scapy.all as scapy, which is all.py file, this file has a lot of python files imported inside it, but it doesn't have the arping() function inside it, that's why VS code says 'scapy.all' has no 'arping' member

in the other hand, you will find the arping() function is defined in a file called l2.py inside the layers folder under scapy >>

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py

this layers folder and its python files (including l2.py) are imported inside all.py file

[image: layers folder and its python files inside it are imported inside all.py file]

so the function is not being imported directly, but its imported,

Thats why its a false positive and you don't need to worry about it,

if you want to get rid of this error, you can do >> import scapy.layers.l2 as scapy

but I don't recommend it since you will only import that l2.py file and you wont import all scapy functions and methods